# WordPress How to make URL that go on Plugin method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Actually I want to make a such type of URL in wordpress that when I click on Anchor Text then it will go on plugin method. Where I will keep my logic and then it will redirect to my previous URL.
I need to complete this task on Woo Commerce Subscription Plugin.

Any help will be appreciating.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some data to url querystring for example add /?myaction=dosomething and then you will not need a separate url. Just add code in your plugin to check if that querystring is set

```
if(isset($_GET['myaction']) && $_GET['myaction'] == 'dosomething') {

// do something

}
```

or if you want a url you can create a page anc check if the user is redirected to this page

```
if(is_page('yourpage')) {
 // do something and then
 wp_redirect('your_location');
}
```

Comment: OK I am doing work on woocommerce-subscription plugin. So you are saying that I write this code on woocommerce-subscription.php file ?? in method or outside of the method ??

Comment: it should be outside of the method because it should be called automatically when any page is loaded and check if it has to do the task. I am not familiar with the plugin you are modifying so I cannot give you exact piece of code, just describing the way how it can be done.